# Uploading venv folder on github

Tags: github, python-venv, virtual-environment

Is it necessary to upload venv folder that itself contains 100's of files along with other folders and files of the same project to GitHub?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer no. In your gitignore file add the venv to ignore all the files inside your venv fold. Basically your venv fold store all the dependency for your projects, you could use pip freeze to generate the requirement.txt which others can use this file to reproduce the same environment as you did. Plus, the files inside your venv will be huge because it contains entire packages you installed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do that. What you can do is :

1. Remember your project python version.
2. Generate your Django project dependencies file `requirement.txt`.

   -Create requirement.txt file use: `pipreqs /path/to/your/project/` (I recommend `pipreqs`, it creates a project level requirement.txt file. You can also use `pip freeze` or other commands)

   -Install all dependencies from it: `pip install -r requirements.txt`, make sure `pip` belongs to your virtualenv python other than OS default pip

Then you can easily install a brand new virtual env and install all dependencies.